# How to write PickByValue type?

Tags: typescript

The `Pick` type is included with TypeScript. It's implementation is as follows:

```
type Pick<T, K extends keyof T> = {
  [P in K]: T[P];
};
```

How would you write a `PickByValue` type such that the following works:

```
type Test = {
  includeMe: 'a' as 'a',
  andMe: 'a' as 'a',
  butNotMe: 'b' as 'b',
  orMe: 'b' as 'b'
};

type IncludedKeys = keyof PickByValue<Test, 'a'>;
// IncludedKeys = 'includeMe' | 'andMe'
```

Comment: Do you want `PickByValue<Test, 'a' | 'b'>` to be equivalent to `Test` or equivalent to `{}`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Assuming you intend `Test` to be this:

```
type Test = {
  includeMe: 'a',
  andMe: 'a',
  butNotMe: 'b',
  orMe: 'b'
};
```

and assuming that you want `PickByValue<T, V>` to give all the properties which are *subtypes* of `V` (so that `PickByValue<T, unknown>` should be `T`), then you can define `PickByValue` like this:

```
type PickByValue<T, V> = Pick<T, { [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends V ? K : never }[keyof T]>
type TestA = PickByValue<Test, 'a'>; // {includeMe: "a"; andMe: "a"}
type IncludedKeys = keyof PickByValue<Test, 'a'>; // "includeMe" | "andMe"
```

But if all you want is `IncludedKeys`, then you can do that more directly with `KeysMatching<T, V>`:

```
type KeysMatching<T, V> = {[K in keyof T]: T[K] extends V ? K : never}[keyof T];
type IncludedKeysDirect = KeysMatching<Test, 'a'> // "includeMe" | "andMe"
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKhDOwoF4oG8BQVtQJYDsBjAGwFcATCAWQgC4oByAQwYBoscn9yb7m2O2AEalgAOQD2wXoyECcUCQCcZDORgC+Abgy7QkKAAVchANYAhEADUmZCAB4YrKFYB8KIydOPnaKAG0AaTx8KFMIEAkAM1gAXXoYINioCAAPYAhueBcoAH4oYPp8CAA3CCUoDX9wyJiYWNcMfWg4RABBD2MzSxs7RwRgZ35XLSgAejH0AhIKajooACImBdGuHnmlhY0m8GgASSIySnJAiOzUGujPbutbUgdWwcYWEfHJhemjuYWoAB9FtY0BZ6XYFM5UJjAQgACwIAHMfC53Kg0EEQmEIld6gkkil0plyNkrHkClAiqVylVLnVYjpmlADjNjqcQPAACK4JQQQhIVAs+AQqGw-AIx5DF5vRafWZAv4A7hAoA)

Comment: After reflecting on this I realized `KeysMatching` was a little more flexible for my specific use case. I came close with my initial tries but wasn't quite getting there. Thanks so much!

Comment: very nice answer

`type IntermediateType { includeMe: includeMe", andMe: "andMe,  butNotMe: never,  orMe: never }` 

and

`type Result = IntermediateType[string]` produces 
`"includeMe" | "andMe" | never | never`, but `never` is stripped out, so it results in `"includeMe" | "andMe"`

Answer (score 0):

As of TypeScript 4.1, you can use an `as` clause to simplify the mapping:

```
type Test = {
  includeMe: 'a',
  andMe: 'a',
  butNotMe: 'b',
  orMe: 'b'
};

type PickByValue<T, V> = { [K in keyof T as T[K] extends V ? K : never]: T[K] };

type IncludedKeys = keyof PickByValue<Test, 'a'>;
// IncludedKeys = 'includeMe' | 'andMe'
```

[Link to playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKhDOwoF4oG8BQUoEsB2AxgDYCuAJhALIQBcUA5AIb0A0WUjeZ1dTr7AIxLAAcgHtgPBgP7YxAJyn0ZGAL4BuDBlCQoABRwEA1gCEQANUakIAHhgso5gHwp0UANoBpXHihGIIGIAZrAc8LBeALpQEAAewBBc4eZQAPxQ3nR4EABuEPKRdDBRUBpaOtAAkoSkFGSeAeGo-oEhBsZmltZ2CMAOfE6aAPRDUNXE5BD1ja70%20BMU1PRQAD4MnNwQ9BhAA)