# How to set function's param as a key from interface

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have interface and object which represents this interface:

```
MyInterface {
  variableOne: string;
  variableTwo: boolean;
  variableThree: boolean; 
  ...
}
```

Also I have function **toggleFunction(x)** which gets a key and toggles it in my object.
Which type do I need to set in param **x** in my toggle function to use it for toggle all boolean key in my object?

For example I need something like: **`toggleFunction(x: TYPE?)`**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to write PickByValue type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55150760/how-to-write-pickbyvalue-type)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [keyof](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#index-types).

```js
function toggleFunction(x: keyof MyInterface): void {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a conditional mapped type that I usually call `KeysMatching`:

```
type KeysMatching<T, V> = { [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends V ? K : never }[keyof T];
```

And then `toggleFunction()` can be defined like this:

```
declare const o: MyInterface; // or wherever it comes from
function toggleFunction(x: KeysMatching<MyInterface, boolean>) {
    o[x] = !o[x];
}

toggleFunction("variableTwo"); // okay
toggleFunction("variableThree"); // okay
toggleFunction("variableOne"); // error!
```

Hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ts=3.6.3#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIE8CS5rycgbwFgAoZc5ANzimDgCMAbCAeRAgC5kBnMWkAOYBuUhSo06TCABUA7gHsu9efOZwQIshWq0GzaQAsoETsmWqI6zWID0NgHSPSAX1Kkw6AA4oA0hHTcqHBgCAagAgA80gA0yABqAHzIALyEyADaPsigyADW-vIwyNIAulzSmSXIEAAekCAAJtzxyAD8yFlc7JTQyM7p+eiFxSWapA0QCIw0KAjyILzIimhYOLCIEKQwAK4gCGDA88hg8gICzABiu-uHIAAUNVx+AUEhYYIRGNiQ60ix5moQAkAJSEUQUeTpGpVVIAQkh0M0rhI7lO5wgVz2B3mdwARDpJPoFLjgUJkHYlrk4OhUWdLtdsfd8RI9DIjCYSWSKfIqTSSCc6RiGbc8QTWWwIJzyTZqlAoPIoLCgA)

Comment: Could you please explain a little the last part of your code: ```[keyof T]```
For what it is?

Comment: It's a [lookup type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#keyof-and-lookup-types).  If you have an object type `T` and a key (or union of keys) of that object type `K`, then `T[K]` is the type of the property at that key (or the union of properties at those keys).  For example, `{a: string, b: number, c: boolean}["a" | "b"]` is `string | number`.