# Filter interface keys for a sub-list of keys based on value type

Tags: typescript

**Problem**

Given a TypeScript interface that is being treated as a map
(relating unique key types to non-unique value types), can one extract
the key types that map to a specified value type?

As a concrete example, starting with the `WindowEventMap` in `lib.dom.d.ts`...

```
interface WindowEventMap 
    extends GlobalEventHandlersEventMap, WindowEventHandlersEventMap {
    "abort": UIEvent;
    "afterprint": Event;
    "beforeprint": Event;
    "beforeunload": BeforeUnloadEvent;
    "blur": FocusEvent;
    // ...
}
```

There is a built-in operator `keyof` for getting all the keys:

```
type FullKeyList = keyof WindowEventMap;
// gives: FullKeyList = "'abort' | 'afterprint' | 'beforeprint' | ..and 93 more"
```

Is there some expression that might filter only the keys which map to value type `KeyboardEvent`?:

```
// Goal:
type SubKeyList = SomeExpression<WindowEventMap, KeyboardEvent>;
// would give: SubKeyList = "'keyup' | 'keypress' | 'keydown'"
```

**Solution Attempt**

TypeScript has the Conditional Type expression:

```
T extends U ? X : Y
```

So this is a reasonable try:

```
type Filter<K extends keyof M, V, M> = M[K] extends V ? K : never;
```

It filters individual types:

```
// Passes this test:
type FilteredExample1 = Filter<'keyup', KeyboardEvent, WindowEventMap>;
// gives FilteredExample1 = "'keyup'"

// Passes this test:
type FilteredExample2 = Filter<'blur', KeyboardEvent, WindowEventMap>;
// gives FilteredExample2 = "never"
```

Can it filter a union of types and return a new union?  Starts off looking good:

```
// Passes this test:
type FilteredUnionExample1 = Filter<'keyup' | 'keydown', KeyboardEvent , WindowEventMap>;
// gives FilteredUnionExample1 = "'keyup' | 'keydown'"
```

But the union fails if one or more members of the union fails:

```
// Fails this test:
type FilteredUnionExample2 = Filter<'keyup' | 'keydown' | 'blur', KeyboardEvent, WindowEventMap>;
// gives FilteredUnionExample2 = "never" (and not sub-union "'keyup' | 'keydown'")

// And so, it also fails the end-goal usage:
type AllKeysUnion = keyof WindowEventMap;
type FilteredUnionExample3 = Filter<AllKeysUnion, KeyboardEvent , WindowEventMap>;
// gives FilteredUnionExample3 = "never" (not sub-union "'keyup' | 'keypress' | 'keydown'")
```

Is there a solution to this problem?

Comment: I'm inclined to close this as a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55150760/how-to-write-pickbyvalue-type)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I usually call this `KeysMatching`:

```
type KeysMatching<T, V> = {[K in keyof T]: T[K] extends V ? K : never}[keyof T];

type SubKeyList = KeysMatching<WindowEventMap, KeyboardEvent>
// type SubkeyList = "keydown" | "keypress" | "keyup"
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=3#code/C4TwDgpgBA0hIGcCyBDYBjAFgSwHYHMAeAFQBooA1APigF4oBvAbRijygGt4B7AMymIBdAFwCWgqBAAewCLgAmCSlAD8sKKNwQAbhABOAXyZcQfAYIDcAWABQt0JCgBlAK4AjOCAAy2BMDqw8MhoWHhEAOp48twA7gCiurjAqGDknm7cKHryCXLAVLYA9IVQDtCubiY+fgEARCbRMbi1UAA+UPXwYHoQCAgt7Z0gLmC1QA)

Comment: Nice!  I had to break it apart to understand it.  If it might help anyone else;
consider it as two steps: 1) Take a map K -> V
and produce a new map K -> K' where each K' is either K itself (if good) or 'never', 2) harvest all the values of the new map.  In code:
`type KeyKeyprimeMap<T, V> = {[K in keyof T]: T[K] extends V ? K : never};
type ValueOf<T> = T[keyof T];
type KeysMatching<T, V> = ValueOf<KeyKeyprimeMap<T,V>>;`