# Using Typescript's Pick to retrieve all keys of a certain type

Tags: typescript

Is there a way to use `Pick<T, K>` to extract all keys of a certain type?

Example:

```js
type MyObject = {
  a: string;
  b: number;
  c: string;
  d: boolean;
}
```

I want to extract all `string` types, so final type will be:

```js
type NewType = {
  a: string;
  c: string;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to write PickByValue type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55150760/how-to-write-pickbyvalue-type)

Comment: Nope, not really, unless I misunderstood the question & answer in your link. That seemed to be filtering by a specific value, but I wanted to filter by a specific type (unless the answer works for types as well?). The accepted answer below was what I was after.

Comment: The question I linked is about types. The word "value" in this context is as opposed to "key", i.e. `Pick` picks by key type and `PickByValue`  picks by value type.

Comment: The answer below is practically identical to the answer to the linked duplicate, by the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you'll need to extract all keys which have `string` value types:

```
type StringKeys<T> = { [P in keyof T]: T[P] extends string ? P : never }[keyof T]

type NewType = Pick<MyObject, StringKeys<MyObject>>; // { a: string; c: string; }
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiDyAjAVhAxsKBeKBvAUFEVAIYBcUAzsAE4CWAdgOYDchxiFDArgLaIQabYlDQVq9ZsOIATCogD2CgDYQSDNgF98%20UJCgBlWoyYBpCCEoAeACoA%20bHigBtAApRGUANYWFAMygbAF0KGzcgqAgAD2AIBhlKKmNmKAB%20KHcuCAA3QShNZx8Qf0CgnT1oADkIAHcbcGgcVzo0Lys4JFQMABpDZLMLaw6UdGA7OxYoAHopp3IkyVZRcX7JzSggA)

Comment: Thanks. This was what I needed. I made it more generalized by changing the signature to `KeysByType<T, K> = = { [P in keyof T]: T[P] extends K ? P : never }[keyof T]`

Comment: In TypeScript 4.1, this can be a one-liner: `type StringEntries<T> = { [P in keyof T as T[P] extends string ? P : never]: T[P] }`.