# Typescript omit getters setters readOnly for Partial data?

Tags: javascript, typescript, api-design, entity-component-system

how i can omit **getters,setters,methods** in `Partial<>` data ?

Or existe a way to get this kind of architecture with typescript ?

I need a types with full access, and a types without readOnly.

I try make a small example here, see note://

```js
export const $A = (() => {
    class A {
        _uid?: string = 'generateUID()';
        _title?: string = '';
        children?: A[] = [];
        B?: InstanceType<typeof $B['B']> = $B.create();
        get Title() {
            return this._title || this._uid;
        }
        constructor(data: Partial<A> = {}) {
            Object.assign(this, data);
        }
        getFullTitle() {
            return this._title + this._uid;
        }
    }
    function create(data?: Partial<A>) {
        return new A(data);
    }
    function renderer(A: A) {
        //#1 Allow full access public A in this renderer entity
        const { Title, _title, _uid } = A; // acces all props autorized here
        const fulltitle = A.getFullTitle(); // acces methods autorized here
        const childTitle = A.children[0]?.Title; // acces child props autorized here
    }

    return {
        create,
        renderer,
        A,
    };
})();
export const $B = (() => {
    class B {
        _foo?: string = '';
        get Foo() {
            return this._foo + 'foo';
        }
        constructor(data: Partial<B> = {}) {
            Object.assign(this, data);
        }
    }
    function create(data?: Partial<B>) {
        return new B(data);
    }
    function renderer(B: B) {}

    return {
        create,
        renderer,
        B,
    };
})();

// API
//#2 Partial props only (omit methods,getter,setter) for a higth level API !
$A.create({ Title: '' }); // should not visible and lint error !
$A.create({ getFullTitle: () => '' }); // should not visible and lint error !
// want allow only this structure for higth API
$A.create({
    _title: '',
    _uid: '',
    B: $B.create(),
    children: [$A.create({ _title: '', _uid: '' }), $A.create({ _title: '', _uid: '' })],
});
```

What i want is inside `function renderer(A: A) {` able to use all public props methodes,getter,setters.
And inside `function create(data?: Partial<A>)` allow only partial datas (without getters,setters,methodes).

So i want a trick to for get only yellow props here, when i use `create()`
[image]

I try many scenario without success, Always hit a wall somewhere ! if you have a another's way to structure this ?
thanks

Comment: Please remove unneeded code, and keep the code most relevant to what you want to accomplish. As from the title, the problem seems general not much specific to the code provided. Possibly, please, create an easy, well-readable example.

Comment: yep ,  remove all unnecessary code, all props are all necessary in this context. Remove one will allow cheating and make false positive.

Comment: i am just searching a solution for omit getter,setter,methods in ts and keep my ECS architecture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To my knowledge, you cannot detect getters or setters in the type system; see [microsoft/TypeScript#10196](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10196) for more information.  It is [said](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10196#issuecomment-238108431) there that

> Interfaces make no distinction between regular properties and accessor properties--it's an implementation detail left up to the implementer of the interface.

---

If you want to detect properties whose values are function-typed, you can use `KeysMatching` from the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55150760/how-to-write-pickbyvalue-type):

```
type KeysMatching<T, V> = { [K in keyof T]-?: T[K] extends V ? K : never }[keyof T];

type MethodKeysOfA = KeysMatching<A, Function>;
// type MethodKeysOfA = "getFullTitle"
```

If you want to detect properties marked as `readonly` (and getter-only properties count), you can do so with `ReadonlyKeys` from the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49579094/typescript-conditional-types-filter-out-readonly-properties-pick-only-requir):

```
type IfEquals<X, Y, A = X, B = never> =
    (<T>() => T extends X ? 1 : 2) extends
    (<T>() => T extends Y ? 1 : 2) ? A : B;
type ReadonlyKeys<T> = {
    [P in keyof T]-?: IfEquals<{ [Q in P]: T[P] }, { -readonly [Q in P]: T[P] }, never, P>

type ReadonlyKeysOfA = ReadonlyKeys<A>
// type ReadonlyKeysOfA = "Title"
```

You could then combine these to produce your "partial" `A`:

```
type MyPartialA = Omit<A, MethodKeysOfA | ReadonlyKeysOfA>
/* type MyPartialA = {
     _uid?: string | undefined;
     _title?: string | undefined;
    children?: A[] | undefined;
    B?: B | undefined;
} */
```

If you use `MyPartialA` instead of `Partial<A>` for the type of the `data` parameter in `create()`, you get the behavior you're looking for:

```
$A.create({ Title: '' }); // error!
$A.create({ getFullTitle: () => '' }); // error!

$A.create({
    _title: '',
    _uid: '',
    B: $B.create(),
    children: [$A.create({ _title: '', _uid: '' }), $A.create({ _title: '', _uid: '' })],
}); // okay
```

---

It's also possible that you want to think of `MyPartialA` as the set of *optional* properties from `A`.  That is, instead of *excluding* methods and readonly properties, you *include* things which might not be present in `A`.  If so, you could use the `OptionalKeys` type from the answer to  [the same question with `ReadonlyKeys`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49579094/typescript-conditional-types-filter-out-readonly-properties-pick-only-requir):

```
type OptionalKeys<T> = { [K in keyof T]-?:
    ({} extends { [P in K]: T[K] } ? K : never)
}[keyof T];

type OptionalKeysOfA = OptionalKeys<A>;
// type OptionalKeysOfA = "_uid" | "_title" | "children" | "B"
```

You can see that this leads to the same `MyPartialA` as before:

```
type MyPartialA = Pick<A, OptionalKeysOfA>;
/* type MyPartialA = {
   _uid?: string | undefined;
   _title?: string | undefined;
   children?: A[] | undefined;
   B?: B | undefined;
} */
```

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEB1AFiALkg3gKDySKUwE8ZkBpCUqAWS3jQEtgBzAHgBUAaJANQB8SALy4kAbUpJWSANY0A9gDMkXALoBaAPwAuNVPVIIAD0wRgAEygCk2pNP3AIANwgAnJAF8JC0irV1AG4CYhJyZABJZQBRAEcAVxAAGygOAA0+AE0+AEFRJEykACEC5zd3YRFCMOIACm5BOoBKUWEuYzMLa0K7JABGJH0AJlbTcysoGtqkBq4m1pF2zomerL7Bkdb7fP1ikLCyCiQAJQgQS0VgZNJqWkaC-BmiCQAFGWB5JVUNHX1o+JJVIcHCSACKHyQr3U+i4byMXj4oM07nOl2upHBkOhsPh3j45Q8fFegmm3l830CITJR2QAHkYJhmFcUnc0vNHpJpLI-AFfnoyWE6jgvCtujZQW9IZQYQYZd4+o4kIT3M0yT5eT9ggQyfArlBsAASfJiOotNq4ULPeDJEBQGz5J7PMIAfQSzEseiQBvcrDYBQA5GwLB4sBAAKqRAAiLQDB2dxBdTMwyQgXp9fsDccF1pYyUsqOAXtyEiMYlL8YTJS9kWABpAwEQXAiHFpAUNxQkAeKAfUVSQHYAdPBUWGWpWE8HsFxmCmIOanVWwqjMAl3J9MCwoIOk7PU0gAD4HkhbnfuywT51eHMzPV1zDuBLwTCKdx1SxYED6V4gdxMlIcLk-Yiq0i5LkQdIAEYAFYQM+g52lAzBsMAdSbswUB8B+mAgM0l7PNe4FTgAYgkyTJDOc4LjeCYrmuG6nruc4AIRIAA1CeGFnh6zH4TMhEEVaMy0kgdAQJuiiWGydLKCaDg0PQjAsOwgF8KRjZMlcgh8UgAD0unhMcYkSVJCkyXJABEJFkRRe4QBZQm1CJZwXFcNzSbJBQuei7kKYBpLOvphnIN5bm3GZnliBZlGpg5NEiXQpA-n+zApLkdJgLOBQZbOqmieJaCSR5+THqFGLFQFzy6QAVMFolJb+-7JHJYEJm6Hrpg+mbHgkVgQMorAQBeNG1Exqadb67CHkgvWWP1g3DeBTDMPmhbFqW02zfNziLUuxReqUPV9QNO06aK1W6Y5hwREgDKaaAyTFdljLMg9bL+TpQUiXdr2shFlntZYFnTRZY32SDy2rRYwPHhZxQOc6CUNSlaUFK8zDwHIeU-Syj3-dpNE1XViXJU1LUjUQgMTd1M3HQtOmJsm436BmU1HXNJ1DQzRCQwWFjrUY7PbVzFPVnsm106dNHnZdNHKL1z6vUgI7nOY76fnY+gk41qXNaBotIHR67KhAADuSC5OrOF4dLcsK-dhvdB4Hh1Lk+i5Pr4H6QAxIMuTkYo5vy+RSAIIg9pIDACSQckGMW5C6E2IWc2op4FjJqQBt3ga4gxRAfBgwX54KmIuRBHpBlh9AochzA7iKDANggAkL6+gAXkNSBoM7Wf6tgwfJEzyCl4O1nkXn44V6H8Dh0gkAmU3LevswHeWF3PdLX3yt5pYecFLkw474WzESAADOo2iDnn5dBVXNi85H9eN6HS-t533eorbNFG58rXWqO5geAG2Ts7dwQDwK5HAQRCcXhmjjkctnI0pRTTmiWJaZ0NpEIlHQUuF0yhFCKGplNMQAZsxEXEkgYiBDqLgWXOJeinFtx4IIexJAAZ8GKDIUuASVZEGPmfK+K2X4oQ6wAsUYCsCcG0NujBOCmAEL2mQqhROWFPw23Ajw2omiwjyw0krFWY5sIgC9KTXWHBxGeyXD-E25tihCPUYJZ0ujFZXEdn1VOdRih7FAt4K6xBrF-1vAA-OwCnapygVWYoEStEwLgTbMkQVcivEiAk3S3thgiJRskR+DcbBhVmIoTK2B56FWsDwKc5gwFQHEpU1o+DPAgC7shTcSBUxuGyUkyISBmKOWNMOYJwo1B2X0KQ7weEp4eHru4HpYQ+kGLVqCMetk5z6FQcIUZsCb4GUma+HpZI5kDMCUgMGIyAzRNdOeU55ziBeIHMUfpqt5zNGuTzI+Fh9ASAOY8wZJy2FnOOZcv5Yy+BfLHKCX5pCi4elOWM9Q0TNlT0UHIEAmc8BeCAA)

Comment: thanks you so much for provide many others solutions, i will look if one make me happy or help me. 
I expected something cleaner and native from ts , like `PartialPropsOnly<A>` but it will fine :)