# Typescript: Is it possible to force 'keyof T' to be a string?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have a function typed as follows:

```
const getByPrimaryKey = <E>(list: E[], primaryKey: keyof E): E => {...}
```

Can I add a type validation to the value associated to `primaryKey` ? For exemple:

```
interface User {
  id: string
  name?: string
  age: number
}

const users: User[] = [{id: '1', age: 1}]

getByPrimaryKey<User>(users, 'id') // OK since id is a string
getByPrimaryKey<User>(users, 'name') // NOT OK because name maybe undefined
getByPrimaryKey<User>(users, 'age') // NOT OK because age is a number
```

Comment: `keyof T` in this case would be `'id' | 'name' | 'age'`, all of which are strings; I think you mean you want a key whose associated value is of type `string`. So you want the `KeysMatching` type from this Q&A: [How to write PickByValue type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55150760/how-to-write-pickbyvalue-type)

Comment: I updated my question to be more clear. I am talking about the type of the value.
I just answered my own question 

Comment: I do not see any relation between your question and your own answer to it. By adding a second type parameter you break the use-case examples which provide one type parameter, and your type parameter `PK` is only bounded by `keyof E` so there is nothing stopping it from being `'name'` or `'age'`.

Comment: You're right. My original question get out of my mind and I post a solution that works in my real-life case. Thanks for reminding me.

Comment: why `getByPrimaryKey<User>(users, 'age') // NOT OK because age is a number` is not ok?

Comment: @captain-yossarian because I will use index primaryKey in an object, so I don't want the picked property to be something else than a string (like undefined, or a subobject).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to combine a couple of [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html).

To get all keys that are non-optional:

```
type RequiredKeys<T> = { [K in keyof T]-?: ({} extends { [P in K]: T[K] } ? never : K) }[keyof T];
```

Get all keys that have a specific type of the value:

```
type TypeMatchingKeys<T, V> = { [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends V ? K : never }[keyof T];
```

Then you can use the intersection of both:

```
type NonOptionalTypeMatchingKeys<T, V> = TypeMatchingKeys<T, V> & keyof Pick<T, RequiredKeys<T>>;
const getByPrimaryKey = <E>(list: E[], primaryKey: NonOptionalTypeMatchingKeys<E, string>): E => {
    ...
}
```