# How can I get typed Object.entries() and Object.fromEntries in Typescript?

Tags: arrays, typescript, object

When I use `Object.fromEntries(entries)` or `Object.entires(obj)` in typescript for my typed/const `entries` arrays or `objt` objects, I am losing the types to `any` or a broad type.

I can manually assign generic types (e.g. `Record<string, number>`) in some cases, but setting types of each pair/key is tedious.

Here is an example of what I want.

### Typed Object.fromEntries(entries)

```
const myArrayOfPairs = [["a", 5], ["b", "hello"], ["c", false]] as const;

// The type of the following is "any"
const myTypelessObject = Object.fromEntries(myArrayOfPairs);

// I want the type of this one to be: { a: 5; b: "hello"; c: false; }
const myTypedObject = createTypedObjectFromEntries(myArrayOfPairs);
```

### Typed Object.entries(obj)

```
const myOldObject = {
    x: 6,
    y: "apple",
    z: true
};

// The type of the following is [string, string | number | boolean][]
const myEntries = Object.entries(myOldObject);

// I want the type of this one to be more specific.
// i.e.: (["x", number] | ["y", string] | ["z", boolean])[]
const myTypedEntries = getTypedObjectEntries(myOldObject);
```

Answer (score 13):

### Object.Entries(obj) -- Object to Array of KeyValue Pairs

This one is relatively straightforward.  Using `[K in keyof OBJ_T]` you can get the keys, and `OBJ_T[K]` gives the relative value.

Here is a simple implementation of it:

```
// ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ Utils ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

type ObjectType = Record<PropertyKey, unknown>;
type PickByValue<OBJ_T, VALUE_T> // From https://stackoverflow.com/a/55153000
    = Pick<OBJ_T, { [K in keyof OBJ_T]: OBJ_T[K] extends VALUE_T ? K : never }[keyof OBJ_T]>;
type ObjectEntries<OBJ_T> // From https://stackoverflow.com/a/60142095
    = { [K in keyof OBJ_T]: [keyof PickByValue<OBJ_T, OBJ_T[K]>, OBJ_T[K]] }[keyof OBJ_T][];

// ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ Typed Function ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

function getTypedObjectEntries<OBJ_T extends ObjectType>(obj: OBJ_T): ObjectEntries<OBJ_T> {
    return Object.entries(obj) as ObjectEntries<OBJ_T>;
}

// ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ Test ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

const myOldObject = {
    x: 6,
    y: "apple",
    z: true
};

const myTypelessEntries = Object.entries(myOldObject); // type: [string, string | number | boolean][]

const myTypedEntries = getTypedObjectEntries(myOldObject);
type myTypedEntiresType = typeof myTypedEntries;  // type: (["x", number] | ["y", string] | ["z", boolean])[]
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEFUBcEsBsGcBQkCeAHApqA8gIwFYYDGkAKulgLygBKxA9gE4AmAPAAqP2aOoDSGFABpQAVwB2Aa3H0A7uIB8AbmQVQ7aEUkAhFADUAhrFEZW2bQCkA+qRF6AggBlwAURsLQIUADEuAW1AAC0hINHgALhB4SAMtegA3DEYAM1g5ADoiej9gA2AAVnyARnyAZgAGSsRQGtBqDS0zSxsRAG9QAG0+UGhxUElBemScZtIAXXCR61IusdAMAA9IDHFmeFAHZzdSUAB+UG7J8QxExlAAXw6BlCGpmzHlVUwcAmJIF3FIRmgMeCbpjxeXzZIIhMKRYDRWKSBJJVIZLI5PIANnKRQALAAmcoATny1Vq1HaXR6fWut3M0wmnXJwwaOn0RhM-xadxmfAeIkpNlmc0utLZYw6YxUiCBEhI0Ho4kQyQlMGloAA5hgyBRmHhCCQPl8fn9uTtFstVutNW9yJgFAAKegESYGgCU9te2s+31+LNIHlaBJqjFVokYfTNJHSK11vxtBAdoAMppd7zdes9j3OiDFYFIv0giCy4mioD8KGwsA1CbqoB9tVAC0myKEvtAKEmACIDGg0LAMC2G9WAF6TL4mRDnUV5gtFi0YLvweA693raghyBhpORoslstayAOpSeMCoTCTDrRb7iJUiU+9JWgAA+oHEoj8uCSd9AuHo9C7BnEQrG6fHSBCxQKdmHnPUKxVNVMC3N5wPXYtS2XXcniwSd1R1aB-XgKcK0PDBbnQmD4PgPd91AfDJitDoWwWHsHyfF9GDme8aJQeir3PFjOhbPt6I-L8MB-MYHWFIA). **Note** that you need `es2019` to be the target in Configs.

### Object.fromEntries(entries) -- Array of KeyValue Pairs to Object

This is one a bit more challenging.

You need to first extract the internal array pairs using `infer`, and then merge the result using the common `UnionToIntersection` utility type.

Here is the best I could come up with:

```
// ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ Utils ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

// Data Types
type EntriesType = [PropertyKey, unknown][] | ReadonlyArray<readonly [PropertyKey, unknown]>;

// Existing Utils
type DeepWritable<OBJ_T> = { -readonly [P in keyof OBJ_T]: DeepWritable<OBJ_T[P]> };
type UnionToIntersection<UNION_T> // From https://stackoverflow.com/a/50375286
    = (UNION_T extends any ? (k: UNION_T) => void : never) extends ((k: infer I) => void) ? I : never;

// New Utils
type UnionObjectFromArrayOfPairs<ARR_T extends EntriesType> =
    DeepWritable<ARR_T> extends (infer R)[] ? R extends [infer key, infer val] ? { [prop in key & PropertyKey]: val } : never : never;
type MergeIntersectingObjects<ObjT> = {[key in keyof ObjT]: ObjT[key]};
type EntriesToObject<ARR_T extends EntriesType> = MergeIntersectingObjects<UnionToIntersection<UnionObjectFromArrayOfPairs<ARR_T>>>;

// ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ Typed Functions ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

function createTypedObjectFromEntries<ARR_T extends EntriesType>(arr: ARR_T): EntriesToObject<ARR_T> {
    return Object.fromEntries(arr) as EntriesToObject<ARR_T>;
}

// ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ Test for entries->object ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

const myArrayOfPairs = [["a", 5], ["b", "hello"], ["c", false]] as const;

const myTypelessObject = Object.fromEntries(myArrayOfPairs); // type: any

const myTypedObject = createTypedObjectFromEntries(myArrayOfPairs);
type myTypedObjectType = typeof myTypedObject; // type: { a: 5; b: "hello"; c: false; }
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=6#code/PTAEBEEMBdNAVAngBwKYGcBQ0WtAUQDtoAnASwyTVAF5QBtABRIHs0ScBpVRAGlACuhANaEWAd0IBdelNAAfUACVUkACYtCAG0QBBEiUiIAPCVUbtiBszaoOibn0EixkqQD4A3JkwgCADzJ0aDJCAHNQAFUQrSwcanBUVGQAdXJYACMtVGMAeQAhACkAfXh3WlAAb1AAWjN1TR1rUFDQYR4WADNQApL4KQAuCCTU9MgsnN7Spg9QAF9veLxIwjJNeBYASWI7dFQAYxDNY0iAOU3c09LyvwAxVgBbUAALaGhkdAGQYMh94RYAG52TpaCQAOn2LAewEgwAArAAGADMAHY4QAmAAcADZMABIOgACjOFyu8FAqH80FQhDU6FAkEIVgA-KBCcIhiTLqUAJS0coAlhkNSgIaEVBAkh8ynU2n0wnsoahTp2UCbPk0AVCtR81mbUWgcWS7y%20MCnVDiKIxOK4KKrTS5DIAKwO0HuUP0hkQuU6jEgZBI6GMuiUSlKFKpNLpBGI5EouHKNEwoBTw2SaTImWywdD1wjsujhOVqqUPNkoFZSnzUfp9GLJDaPH49dAAMgWjkrOq9GQrGQLUIjasADJQDZ2FweINW%2035gajaqxRK7ItbQBZOxhVDbamB12hMKOl2HINHsoVSr0dpWVrXro9Z39IZnq9ThbYW1EUgUdAbI%20unMw3JGUaxjb94zQRNQA3Egtx3XZ93Cf8TxOe1CA2eC90ONZCFQnDkLdR5PSMH0-QDIMQyA9xqJNPwqFQEVbiEbDNCwTpmKOQd9nqal6LUAj3QeL84wo3NgMjOUwJE%20j3EJSADCGSjeSGYSfz-Z0AKU89KmTVMzGgAQSEHAiwU6R5VIwOSDD5SB6Qs38WAIwDrm8OYfDojBoFAToWAbGlwPQGp3BYDTDkwSFCGCUAHj0AwSN9f1Awqeh6AAIkgVL%20DhKR%20DSjJMtAVLnlQLRQVSnKGFS-YCs6ds9ikORbNACLghNFqvJi%20jsnQdACIqEyzKhezCRi4jvQS8ieU8UA-CWIZGUQHx2uixA%20L6uhuNUXjcH40LCKG2MfxG2KvVIxL0Cmj9qE6naCPoiolnvG60F249oGm2bcCGapICGOFpoyIYipKsrpv2IZatiVBprmIA)

Comment: This is awesome. How the heck one comes up with something like `type ObjectEntries`? Is there a tutorial or something? This is the darkest magic I've seen in a while and I can't really understand it, however the fact that it can't be done in an easy canonical way is quite weird to me.

Comment: You could to all this with type-fest `Entries` : https://github.com/sindresorhus/type-fest . I highly recommend type-fest.

Comment: Also, you could simply modify the return type of `Object.entries` itself without creating the function `createTypedObjectFromEntries`:

`interface ObjectConstructor {
    entries<T extends object>(o: T): Entries<T>
  }`

Comment: Great solution! The only thing I couldn't really figure out was how `DeepWritable<ARR_T> extends (infer R)[]` is distributive. Could you please elaborate a bit?

Answer (score 9):

This is now easier to achieve on TypeScript 5 with the new [`const Type Parameter`](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-5-0/#const-type-parameters).

```
//
// Object.fromEntries
//

const typeSafeObjectFromEntries = <
  const T extends ReadonlyArray<readonly [PropertyKey, unknown]>
>(
  entries: T
): { [K in T[number] as K[0]]: K[1] } => {
  return Object.fromEntries(entries) as { [K in T[number] as K[0]]: K[1] };
};

const myObject = typeSafeObjectFromEntries([
  ["a", 5],
  ["b", "hello"],
  ["c", false],
]); // { a: 5; b: "hello"; c: false } ✅

//
// Object.entries
// (add const param for less broader types (ie. string -> "apple") -> const T extends Record<PropertyKey, unknown>)
//

const typeSafeObjectEntries = <T extends Record<PropertyKey, unknown>>(
  obj: T
): { [K in keyof T]: [K, T[K]] }[keyof T][] => {
  return Object.entries(obj) as { [K in keyof T]: [K, T[K]] }[keyof T][];
};

const myEntries = typeSafeObjectEntries({ x: 6, y: "apple", z: true });
// ["x", number] | ["y", string] | ["z", boolean])[] ✅
// with const param: (["x", 6] | ["y", "apple"] | ["z", true])[] ✅
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-B0Bm5S6xy5W3H1pMNRhNJghprMRUJFmsgbm4BstsVq7sS2WK8oqzXKvWrk25234jcvfdmE9g5k3r7PgHRUGRytiuocgA2EKsRlWm12kIALxypFC3P65KlYPUiOvPoAB8cVYRFwWtW0sQgECwRfREPxJPJ2z5YUYjIFBkRwUJmG9CAVTVHI-0RapanqYDQMRZ1yldCi4MRGAcBwW0eASZC+l5IA)

Comment: Really nice. Just what I was looking for! Do you know if the `const` Type Parameter is possible with TS via JDoc annotations?

Comment: What if I want to pass a custom value for `PropertyKey`? Something like `const result = typeSafeObjectFromEntries<MyEnum>([. . .])`

Comment: @MikeK Not sure how to infer the type of the value when providing a custom `PropertyKey`. This is what I came up with: `type TypedEntries<P extends PropertyKey, V> = ReadonlyArray<readonly [P, V]>;`. Then use it as the type argument `typeSafeObjectFromEntries<TypedEntries<"foo" | "bar", string>>([["foo", "whatever"], ["bar", "whatever2"]]);`