# Type ... is missing the following properties from type ... assigning key and value in empty object using index signature faced error

Tags: typescript, index-signature

I am trying to create it where the object keys are unknown in the beginning (util I got `testArray` from the previous page).

```js
{
  a: [ { key1: 0, key2: 0 }, { key1: 0, key2: 0 }, { key1: 0, key2: 0 } ],
  b: [ { key1: 0, key2: 0 }, { key1: 0, key2: 0 }, { key1: 0, key2: 0 } ]
}
```

```js
interface DemoObject {
  [key: string]: Array<{
    key1: number;
    key2: number;
  }>;
}

const testArray = ["a", "b"];
const innerKeys = ["key1", "key2"];
const demoObject: DemoObject = {};

testArray.forEach((t: string) => {
  demoObject[t] = Array.from({ length: 3 }, () =>
    Object.fromEntries(innerKeys.map((prop) => [prop, 0]))
  );
});
```

However, I got these two error at `object[t]`:

```
Type '{ [k: string]: number; }[]' is not assignable to type '{ key1: number; key2: number; }[]'.
Type '{ [k: string]: number; }' is missing the following properties from type '{ key1: number; key2: number; }': key1, key2
```

Comment: Might be a good idea to name your interface something other than `Object`

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mqyEkm) based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69019874/21637817) work for you? If yes, I'll write an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `innerKeys` should be narrowed, since currently, its type is `string[]`. This can be done by using the [const assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions):

```
// readonly ["key1", "key2"]
const innerKeys = ['key1', 'key2'] as const;

//  "key1" | "key2"
type InnerKey = typeof innerKeys[number];
```

Another problem is that `Object.fromEntries()` is not return the literal type. The easiest fix would be to use `as` assertion to cast it to the correct type, or by using this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69019873/how-can-i-get-typed-object-entries-and-object-fromentries-in-typescript/69019874#69019874) we can create a typed version of the method, though it also calls the assertion at the end.

Testing:

```
testArray.forEach((t) => {
  demoObject[t] = Array.from({ length: 3 }, () =>
    createTypedObjectFromEntries(innerKeys.map((prop) => [prop, 0])),
  );
});
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=6&ts=5.0.4#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-UQlzakaBybGgcQyE0pj4X6L4vIwclIDMEVIFZGK4O4JikPLfi1gE6I736MECHzT40t8i4GjUUDhAmSJKFiDdWKsQKxx7ABGGVxE+PI7XNHsCXazruoc1Yst3bAcCRYhIlARlIgauo2AAckgBaxAWvIFsUFYQlaOwOjYAAiVr9rEQ7hAJfbhwmqbollMh3FZF5FtalbQAW3qNrZVkrugLawFAU7EBa-b1AB86cA9PViFu9w6g9f8bpce62GIDqurITbxoU6BQB0VBiqYiYipKl9sc-dYBJm6AGsi7gyEIMEfnJcloCNAK1Fx-HSugNhoHAl5qai5FyS-QpYmgH4JmxHcxHJVnzW07RdOkwzoszWCayhxHhHQeFPkgZAmanXhWcnacxExRQhSFNymCFFZVjtnAgA)