# Can I use Typescript generics to filter keys from an object based on type?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have a filter function working, but I can't for the life of me find out how to write a generic type that communicates this returned data structure:

```
class Value<T> {
  val: T;

  constructor(val: T){
    this.val = val;
  }

  get(): T {
    return this.val;
  }
}

let data = {
  foo: new Value(123),
  bar: new Value('abc'),
  baz: 'xyz'
}

let filter = (obj: Object): any => {
  let result: any = {};
  for (const [key, val] of Object.entries(obj)) {
    if(val instanceof Value) result[key] = val.get();
  }
  return result;
};

filter(data).foo; // 123
filter(data).bar; // 'abc'
filter(data).baz; // error
```

I've managed to do some somewhat complex things with generics, but I think this is way beyond my depth. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to write PickByValue type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55150760/how-to-write-pickbyvalue-type)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for:

[TS Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/MYGwhgzhAEBqYgK4FMA8AVAfNA3gWAChpoA3BALmnQG5DDjgB7AOwgBcAnRYNxjgCjIhK6AJS56xaGwAWASwgA6IdAC8pBLSLQAvnW0BzZG36iRE7cQ7HEHZtPlKhW4noJvCTVm2gATMGxgahbEAGaMjJTMyADucAgo-ACMAEwAzKIANJIARmAcUbHxSMj8AORgOcBlWblgAF6UZQAeAJ71ZdnuWoRsrQAOyNAAYnIgbMjWvhjY6vjaANoA0tBy9gDWyK2MoVTQkFTLALrQyM0TzL4w8CWoYMyt2AD80CuFJJNHIsen58iX1wSaHuj0kxBeACUbHZ0AM0OhjgsykY2GUjpgwdB3pMtDoegRQohmDw5CxoKExhMOBhfhcrtAoUwONN2Bw1gZMtAietmIwYsxMJh+IwcgArERmEaUybIaZYELQLzsaDWCCIcbBHA6fYwUbjGVyzAucl8aD8JU+BabVqcoQnHbQADyYuQPEU-04cmQEGFYtE4nmUlWu0ECFW3nuwGQDpuKHEqvVbCtWx10GtDr6gwdCfGJ3UQkUKNMxrcVmh9hzbFx+iVjBAyEUIEYBn4FP1An8gVEinCjFE1GgAHpB9BUmlPCwIHWG02W22qfxO2Bu3kOP2hyOKlUyhPWNPG83W9KOwFl4o8vV18PThwOHxCEA)

```ts
type Filtered<T> = {
  [K in keyof T as T[K] extends Value<any> ? K : never]: T[K] extends Value<any>
    ? ReturnType<T[K]['get']>
    : never;
};

function filter<T extends Record<string, unknown>>(obj: T): Filtered<T> {
  const result = {} as Filtered<T>;
  for (const [key, val] of Object.entries(obj)) {
    if (val instanceof Value) result[key as keyof typeof result] = val.get();
  }
  return result;
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're using `ReturnType<T[K]['get']>` instead of just `U` here?  Also, the OP seems to want `filter(data).baz` to be a compiler error and not `undefined`, so more like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mbdpow) (using key remapping but there are other ways of doing it)

Comment: @jcalz The return type of `value.get()` just happens to be `U`, but if it changes, then they won't always be the same. I chose `undefined` to align with runtime semantics, but a more advanced optional key remapping would be nicer, I agree. Feel free to edit that in.

Comment: @jsejcksn This is really great! Thank you! jcalz is right in that I would like to have it be a compiler error. What would this more advanced optional key remapping look like?

Comment: @Craig I updated it to include jcalz's suggestion

Comment: @jsejcksn Perfect! Thank you. There is so much going on here, I'll need to sit down and really study it sometime. If you or anyone else knows good resources that could help me break this down that would be a very welcome added bonus to all of this help I've gotten so far.

Comment: @Craig TypeScript can seem daunting (and this is certainly beyond basics), but the handbook is honestly a superb guide, and has just been getting better and better. I encourage you to read through it as you would any manual. You might find the [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) section of specific interest here.