# How to solve the problem caused by using the "as" keyword

Tags: typescript

I had this problem
Why do I always have to fill in the details

```
type Doc = Record<string,any>


type DocFilter<T extends Doc> = {[k in keyof T as T[k] extends (()=>void) ? never:k]:T[k]}



const doc1 = {aaaa:'',bbbb:1,c:()=>{}} 


function test1 <T extends Partial< typeof doc1>,>(opt:{prop:T}){}

test1({
  prop:{
    aaaa:'',
    bbbb:1, // When I enter the "bbbb" field, there is a prompt .This was to be expected
  }
})
```

test2   I want to filter out the function field
// Why do I always have to fill in the details

```
function test2 <T extends Partial<DocFilter< typeof doc1>>,>(opt:{prop:T}){}

test2({
  prop:{
    aaaa:'', // When I enter the first field, the correlation keyword prompts all fields.  For example, enter a to prompt aaaa and b to prompt bbbb  
    b   //But I couldn't get a prompt when I entered the second field .The cause was found because of the ''as' keyword. How to solve this problem?  
  }
})
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=27&ssc=150&pln=27&pc=122#code/FAFwngDgpgBAIgewMYwLwwEpSQgTgEwB4BnEXASwDsBzAGgENKwA+YN8aeZAMXIBsQUXIQAqMKAA9BlfMS5JmaGAG8A2gGsYVGOqhgEAMxhj6ckRoC64qVBlyAFPYCUqZgDcE5fE5gB+GJRQbkIAXOoWIebhAL5sbDiUpDD4yACMSsr0WfQhAOS5tABGxYUhqbRIIc6uytHRMHEGAK6USCDkCJQwgqTpotbSsjAACvS47fR8hN2QUIbJacy0zPYIECAhyhC4a5HRTrXsUL32ysAwMNu7ZxcX2Tn5tOe3JaXlMAD0HzAA6gAWthgAElxJRBLhugCYAAiV7QmAGchQPj4WiQoSwchyeiXHYAW3WMAAdCI-liYAB3UzdBAwQqwSTQNpQfDPWL7NhfbrHEAAJluIKpYJpCP44JgCCaIHRCJabQ6XURyNZzVa7U63NI-P6kkGclG43Ik0IiCQvAEQmmHDmRhSSFSzCWKzWGy2OwgewOsVAPN5p2eVw9N1u9zyBU+33+gJBtnFIChiNwSSVKLR8dgOFwuGR9HVXV0YApeHwuIQBJA2L4fFFyuIRIu3Dw1noBL4UDRsaEMBxIFpV3L3ey3ZkdJF-cJrwuzwuhVuXwAQlLgTAcE0UZRctLqFBpTjx9KKQCujGwRiS+mYMRsJ0SymSySoUh6E0r5TqQZJSP6U+X7B5hf8lMXIdD0IsCHrAAJBAKRFYgED4YJIXJK5CjbPF-AaC52Scc5gCAA)

Comment: What "details" and "prompt" are you referring to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not really sure why your solution doesn't work, but this other way of defining `DocFilter` seems to do what you want. Instead of using `as` to re-map the keys, you can use `Omit` to exclude the ones you don't want. I borrowed `KeysMatching` from [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55153000/12299000).

```
type KeysMatching<T, V> = {[K in keyof T]: T[K] extends V ? K : never}[keyof T];
type DocFilter<T> = Omit<T, KeysMatching<T, () => void>>
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA0hIGcCyBDYBjAFgSwHYHMAeAFQBooA1APigF4oBvAbRijygGt4B7AMymIBdAFwCWgqBAAewCLgAmCSlAD8sKKNwQAbhABOAXyZcQfAYIDcAKFCQoAEW7oAYtgA2svSRr0A8gFtsYBJyOERUDBwCEKgACgBKOhptbmx5KiorG3BoR3Q6KAAlCHRuPXlCBGA9PHxSFFwQTNLcKqh5JwBGAoYUPpRRAHJB8gAjcdHRTvJ0UQSkxgMDKCzeAFdcdGBsblwoWSrOkkkZOUUoAAUUPW2UN0JbCDMO9E6M2O4wYFEGMD1P0TEAzxBgGLIHYCdWIMKxQKB-AEwuFw-oDYakWHIgD0WKgoygKDWwCc3H8YDcEAO+24eImUEw+ggmLBwNWGy2Oz2EIATMdpLIFEorjdsHdCHlXB59IR9jlnl0MlQPl8fgiwIDgaDwRAqtzoZi1cIkcjUcJ0Zi4Ti8QSiSSyRSqcTaeN6YzmVZWSsgA)