# MethodOf type cannot be used to call the method

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I would like to dynamically generate some tests, for that I have to call a method with the method name to be called and then all the test setup is done and the method is called.

So basically I call `createTest('methodName')` instead of `it('methodName', () => ...lotsOfBoringStuff...)`.

For that I would like to type the method appropriately, so I have autocomplete and are sure, that I only call it for the correct methods.

I managed to whip something together that "should work", but TS does complain about incompatible types:

```
type MethodOf<T> = {
  [P in keyof T]: T[P] extends () => unknown ? P : never;
}[keyof T];

function doStuff<T, N extends MethodOf<T>>(t: T, method: N): unknown {
  const meth: () => unknown = t[method]; // <-- boom: {} cannot be assigned to () => unknown
  return meth();
}

const t = {
  abc: 'str',
  foobar: () => 1,
};

doStuff(t, 'foobar');  // <-- works as expected + autocompletion

type T1 = typeof t;
type N1 = MethodOf<T1>; // 'foobar'
type M1 = T1[N1]; // () => number // <-- works as expected
```

Why doesn't TS detect that `T[MethodOf<T>]` is actually a callable method?
Is there an alternative to casting it to `any` before assigning it?

I'm using typescript 4.6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we define a type `OnlyMethods` like this:

```
type OnlyMethods<T> = Pick<T, MethodOf<T>>;
```

Then change the signature of `doStuff` to this:

```
function doStuff<T extends OnlyMethods<T>, N extends MethodOf<T>>(t: T, method: N): unknown {
```

The body of the function now works:

```
function doStuff<T extends OnlyMethods<T>, N extends MethodOf<T>>(t: T, method: N): unknown {
  const meth = t[method]; // not even a type annotation is needed!
  return meth();          // it just WORKS
}
```

I believe this counter-intuitive solution works because `T` is now only methods, and `N` is only keys that correspond to methods, which means `T[N]` is always a method.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=11&ssc=1&pln=7&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAshwAsD2ATA8gMwDwBUB8UAvFAN4CwAUFFANoAKUAlgHZQDWEISGUOAugC5e9PlAgAPYBGYoAzlAAUASiIEArszbMkAd1YB+KAyHMIANwgAnANyUAvjQ5ce-WxUqhIUNMwA2IOERUWVwCYjpGAGM2XAAaWHhkdGx8PDdKDA1I4EYkVhQkAGVgNQwUsUlpOW8-AMTg0PiAOQqpGXlApMxQvAVgIRx4gFt6lCEmpSENLV1WciooSLzZYCgRxCIoYBp1pL5rKAB6Q6gsAFozqAAjJCQhoRI7RYBDZm1Vq+hn2VlGAHNTCgtkhFCpCOpNNo9JRqJZ4GpLKxdso3HZKJQlswVltNvNqM8rpEhAByFaWYmxGFQDC3K7PSxCZSqKAARkpFDs6QoBWKpQwfXixJpSDp5KUByOJ3Olx0SEsbHk3wqkGyECBAGooM81MAkEshmBfPBcsx0RRPNAcCzNhbuFs3BaoE1rcROqhula0pKoELafTiR5wNAYC7eCyaM79t6meCoMw1ENPpZvdKoLL5Yr5BIVVIUEA)