# TypeScript how to call function with its name

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am new to typescript, when I type: (dialog is imported from a library)

```
ipcMain.handle("openDialog", (event, method, config) => {
  return dialog[method](window, config);
});
```

It is working in javascript but it throws `Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'any' can't be used to index type 'Dialog'` in typescript.

After finding some solutions online, none of them can solute this error for me.

That is what I have now:

```
ipcMain.handle("openDialog", (event : any, method : keyof Electron.Dialog, config : any) => {
  return dialog[method](window, config);
});
```

and I only got:

```
This expression is not callable.
  Each member of the union type '{ (browserWindow: BrowserWindow, options: CertificateTrustDialogOptions): Promise<void>; (options: CertificateTrustDialogOptions): Promise<...>; } | ... 6 more ... | { ...; }' has signatures, but none of those signatures are compatible with each other.
```

Any solutions?

Comment: It's hard to say anything without a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), but the reason why it's probably not working is that not all properties of `dialog` can be called with `(window, config)` becasue they, for example, aren't even a function.

Comment: `method: keyof Electron.Dialog` tells typescript that `method` is a property of `Electron.Dialog`, but that doesn't mean `method` must be a function.

Comment: It is a small electron project and I use that for opening dialog from the renderer.
The main problem is even using `keyof typeof dialog`, it still throw an error.
That is hard to show up all codes including config files...

Comment: Maybe I can cast it to a function

Comment: Does this question help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71887374/methodof-type-cannot-be-used-to-call-the-method