# Problem with proper type inference when accessing object keys

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I am trying to write a groupBy generic function in Typescript.
I wanted to limit the groupBy fields to keys of specific type for a given object.
I am using the solution proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54520676/in-typescript-how-to-get-the-keys-of-an-object-type-whose-values-are-of-a-given) and it's working fine limiting the keys I can use. The problem occurs later:

```
type KeysMatchingType<T, V> = {[K in keyof T]-?: T[K] extends V ? K : never}[keyof T];
type GroupByAllowedType = string | number | boolean 

function groupBy<T extends object>(arr: T[], prop: KeysMatchingType<T,GroupByAllowedType>): Map<GroupByAllowedType, T[]> {
  
  const map: Map<GroupByAllowedType, T[]> = new Map()
  return arr.reduce((acc, current) => {
    const key = current[prop]
    const val = acc.get(key)
    
    if(val){
      val.push(current)
    } else {
      acc.set(key, [current]) 
    }
    return acc
  }, map)
}
```

at `const val = acc.get(key)` Typescript is complaining that:

> Type 'T[string]' is not assignable to type 'GroupByAllowedType'

even tho the key used to index `T` is limited by type declaration for the parameter, e.g. `prop` is such a key that `T[prop]` should return either `boolean`, `string` or `number`

I am just wondering is this a limitation of Typescript or am I doing something wrong?
I guess I could use casting with `as`, but generally I try to avoid it.

Comment: Yes, its a limitation. TypeScript has no clue at that point what can and can not be in `T`. It only knows that `T extends object` and that `KeysMatchingType` does return `keyof T`. It does not know that these keys are limited to some type of `T`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the constraint from `object` to this:

```
function groupBy<T extends Record<KeysMatchingType<T, GroupByAllowedType>, GroupByAllowedType>>(arr: T[], prop: KeysMatchingType<T, GroupByAllowedType>): Map<GroupByAllowedType, T[]> {
```

Similarly to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71887374/methodof-type-cannot-be-used-to-call-the-method/72016534#72016534) from a while ago,  you're able to tell TypeScript that you only care about the keys of `T` that correspond to `GroupByAllowedType` simply by using a recursive constraint.

Then as you see [here](https://tsplay.dev/weQpXw), this one change fixes the error :)