# Index Signature with Typescript with Array of Objects

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, index-signature

I've been using Typescript for a few months now, but am stuck with getting my index signatures to work properly.

```
sensorTestData = [
  {
    altitude: 249.74905877223617
    gas: 4361
    humidity: 53.16487239957308
    pressure: 30.100467823211194
    temperature: 69.0322421875
    timestamp: "2022-02-23 00:10:12.377165"
  }, 
  {
    altitude: 249.5376138919663
    gas: 700
    humidity: 53.15552212315537
    pressure: 30.100694114206632
    temperature: 69.07759374999999
    timestamp: "2022-02-23 00:10:13.574070"
  }
 ]
```

The array of objects look like this: `{ temperature: number; humidity: number; pressure: number; altitude: number; gas: number; timestamp: string; }`

I've tried multiple different ways to add [metric: string]: any and can't seem to get anywhere without using "any."

Here is an example of a function I am using with the array of objects:

````
const getMax = (metric: string) => {
    return parseFloat(
      Math.max(...sensorTestData.map((obj: {
            temperature: number;
            humidity: number;
            pressure: number;
            altitude: number;
            gas: number;
            timestamp: string;
          }) => obj[metric])).toFixed(2)
    );

  };
  console.log("maxTemp", getMax("temperature"));
  console.log("maxHumidity", getMax("humidity"));```

Error thrown: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{ temperature: number; humidity: number; pressure: number; altitude: number; gas: number; timestamp: string; }'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{ temperature: number; humidity: number; pressure: number; altitude: number; gas: number; timestamp: string; }'.ts(7053)
````

Comment: Could you please provide a [mre] that defines `sensorTestData` so this can compile without any unrelated errors?

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/WKVgpm) meet your needs? If not, please let me know what's missing.  If so, I could maybe write up an answer (although it could be a duplicate of or strongly related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54520676/2887218))

Comment: @jcalz I'll take a look at your link. Thanks for pointing me in a direction. I've spent the past few days going over different aspects of this and am just currently stuck on it.

Comment: @jcalz That definitely works. Thank you! Now I just need to understand why it works. A bit confused on the T, V, and K variables in the code and why and what it extends.

Answer (score 1):

In order for this to compile without error, you need the `metric` parameter to be more specific than just `string`.  After all, if you pass some arbitrary `string` in to `getMax()` like `getMax("oopsieDaisy")` then you'll be trying to get `Math.max()` of a bunch of `undefined` values (which is probably an error). The compiler error is warning you about this very issue; the compiler has no idea what might happen for an arbitrary `string`.  So you need to make sure that `metric` is one of the known keys of the `sensorTestData` elements.

In fact, it specifically has to be those keys whose value type is known to be `number`; if you call `getMax("timestamp")` you will be getting `Math.max()` of a bunch of `string` values, (which is also probably an error).

If we define the `Data` interface like this to correspond to the elements of `sensorTestData`,

```
interface Data {
  temperature: number;
  humidity: number;
  pressure: number;
  altitude: number;
  gas: number;
  timestamp: string;
}
```

Then we want `metric` to be of type `"temperature" | "humidity" | "pressure" | "altitude" | "gas"` (that's the [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of the known string [literal](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) keys whose values in `Data` are `number`).

If we define a type alias for that:

```
type KeysForNumericData = "temperature" | "humidity" | "pressure" | "altitude" | "gas"
```

And we [annotate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#parameter-type-annotations) the type of `metric` with it:

```
const getMax = (metric: KeysForNumericData) => {
  return parseFloat(
    Math.max(...sensorTestData.map((obj) => obj[metric])).toFixed(2)
  );
};
```

Then that compiles with no error.  And you get type checking when you call `getMax()` also:

```
getMax("temperature"); // okay
getMax("humidity"); // okay
getMax("oopsieDaisy"); // error!
// Argument of type '"oopsieDaisy"' is not assignable to 
// parameter of type 'KeysForNumericData'.
getMax("timestamp"); // error!
// Argument of type '"timestamp"' is not assignable to 
// parameter of type 'KeysForNumericData'.
```

---

That's basically the answer, except that if `Data` ever changes, the type of `KeysForNumericData` will not automatically update.  It might be nice to have the compiler *compute* `KeysForNumericData` in terms of `Data`.  Here's one way to do it:

```
type KeysMatching<T, V> = {
  [K in keyof T]-?: T[K] extends V ? K : never
}[keyof T]

type KeysForNumericData = KeysMatching<Data, number>;
//type KeysForNumericData = "temperature" | "humidity" | "pressure" | "altitude" | "gas"
```

I've defined a utility type called `KeysMatching<T, V>` (explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54520829/2887218) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55153000/2887218) and probably elsewhere) which returns the keys of `T` whose property values are assignable to `V`.
And so to get the keys of `Data` whose values are assignable to `number`, we write `KeysMatching<Data, number>`.

There are a few different ways to implement `KeysMatching`.  A brief explanation of this one: we are [mapping over](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) the keys `K` of `T` and for each property `T[K]` at that key we are checking via [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) if that property is assignable to `number`.  If so, we include that key (`K`), otherwise we exclude it (with [the `never` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-never-type)).  That mapped type (everything before the `[keyof T]`) for `KeysMatching<Data, number>` evaluates to something like `{temperature: "temperature", humidity: "humidity", ... timestamp: never}` where only the `timestamp` key has a `never` property value.  Then we [index into](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) this mapped type with `keyof T`, producing the union of property values, which in this case is `"temperature" | "humidity" | ... | "gas" | never`".  Since `never` is an impossible type, it gets absorbed into all unions (`XXX | never` is equivalent to `XXX`) and so the result is the desired union of keys.

And now if `Data` changes, `KeysForNumericData` will automatically change to fit:

```
interface Data {
  temperature: number;
  humidity: number;
  pressure: number;
  altitude: number;
  gas: number;
  timestamp: string;
  latitude: number;
  longitude: number;
  flavor: string;
  glutenFree: boolean;
}

type KeysForNumericData = KeysMatching<Data, number>;
/* type KeysForNumericData = "temperature" | "humidity" | "pressure" | 
     "altitude" | "gas" | "latitude" | "longitude" */
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.5.4#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-sbiPGCw6SwkaXwmhAsLIAAPnCIqCCI4FQbCyqnGBkFwnkNIoQhfKhj4-iBKYEBgGm3YlgAFPYYC-gwp6ft+B5-pgACUaTFhSyC0CaIDSHAUDBJuWi+BgpGDMgaZgNwFQkHA3akRUcnBKEERRPEklwGQpGkb4LAAFbMakxZadpCQUb+SSMYxFRgL4m7AN2ED8KRRSMVIjFeFG+B+KEWgQBUAmmKRsJSd2kTkLCeYEUR0kBcB3xgeZ6iebIvjeb5vj+YF0kABJ8LBwhhbyhHEQFMFzLC8UEBFRWwr4vhkLIwAQOgwCyHlrnIM+yDQFAYQAIQEB1ACCUCmPu4DIIur4AOTVbV9WNXAzV5ZNlaDiAvhgJo8jAKYIBwCw3nEL43FfBR0DjQ2U00bu+6-vEk0VBVhVRUBjpQqFbUdV1vX9Y+yBDSN9hjRNwhxtNkLOqFy3NYw62bfVO17QdVnHdChFncDoNXV+N2HndD34AQu1OmQiAoAAwtwcCXigbGgJAsCk2g-6lpMMWgVYEhqCJJVisonMmIcSGqnzxgiehBS0iLNiUnyHOi6zr0Q66QSUe4AtEFoGAYXL0uHAJl7a1LXOTDAmsTmELiq5e6u8loVB9putBKCwNXeVTAvhlIr5Y3Rt3M+kp5iRm2Y3kbD5SI+ABUxAg+u760TjDEAXCbOKPB0E5aVqGIXIyHp7C4uFPn2HZ5r+RF6X-imBh4GR4+K6eEAA)

Comment: WOW! Thank you so much for the very thorough answer in terms I am now able to comprehend. I very much appreciate you taking the time to help me with this issue.