# How to write a TypeScript type that extracts properties from another type using an array of keys

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I'm trying to write a TypeScript type that turns a tuple of the keys of an type into a type with only those properties. The following code is the closest I have gotten:

```js
type Primitive = string | number | boolean;
type ExtractProps<TObject, TKeys extends (keyof TObject)[], TExtends = any> = {
    [Index in keyof TKeys as TKeys[Index] extends keyof TObject ? (TObject[TKeys[Index]] extends TExtends ? TKeys[Index] : never) : never ]:
        TKeys[Index] extends keyof TObject ? TObject[TKeys[Index]] : never 
};

type Type = {
    'string': string;
    'number': number;
    'boolean': boolean;
    'array': Array<any>
}

type Test1 = ExtractProps<Type, ['string', 'number', 'array']>;
// Output:
// type Test1 = {
//     string: string | number | any[];
//     number: string | number | any[];
//     array: string | number | any[];
// }
// Desired Output:
// type Test1 = {
//     string: string;
//     number: number;
//     array: any[];
// }
type Test2 = ExtractProps<Type, ['string', 'number', 'array'], Primitive>;
// Output:
// type Test2 = {
//     string: string;
//     number: number;
// }
// Desired Output:
// type Test2 = {
//     string: string;
//     number: number;
// }
type Test3 = ExtractProps<Type, ['string', 'number'], Primitive>;
// Output:
// type Test3 = {
//     string: string | number;
//     number: string | number;
// }
// Desired Output:
// type Test3 = {
//     string: string;
//     number: number;
// }
```

I can only get the type to work properly when the re-mapping expression evaluates to `never` for one of the keys (like `array` in Type2 as the property type does not extend `Primitive`). Is there a way of writing `ExtractProps` so that Type1 and Type3 have the correct property types?

Comment: Why is the second argument a tuple instead of a union?  What does the third argument do?  This looks like a mixture of `Pick` and `PickByValue` as shown https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55150760/how-to-write-pickbyvalue-type

Comment: Can you explain what the "correct" types for `Test1` and `Test3` should be?

Comment: @jcalz There would be no way of re-mapping the keys of a union type. Using `Index in keyof TKeys` will add one property on the resulting object per item in the tuple. I've added the desired output to the code.

Comment: "There would be no way of re-mapping the keys of a union type"; but you don't need to remap the keys of a union type, just use the union type as the keys.  Like, does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/we4g1W) meet your needs? If not, can you explain exactly what the tuple is giving you that the union version doesn't?  If so, I can write up an answer, although it really is just a combination of `Pick` and `PickByValue`.

Comment: @jcalz Thanks, that works perfectly. I needed the tuple so I could use a rest argument to get the types, but I can get the union type easily and pass it into PickByValue. 
`declare function getProps<K extends (keyof Type)[]>(...keys: K): K extends Array<infer E> ? Pick<Type, E & keyof Type> : any;`
`let a = getProps('array', 'string');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for seems to be a combination of [the `Pick<T, K>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#picktype-keys) which produces a type from `T` with only a subset of the known properties, specifically those whose keys are in `K`, and something we can call `PickByValue<T, V>` (as requested in [How to write PickByValue type?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55150760/2887218)) which produces a type from `T` with only a subset of the known properties, specifically those whose values are in `V`.  We can use [key remapping via `as`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as) to write `PickByValue`:

```
type PickByValue<T, V> =
    { [K in keyof T as T[K] extends V ? K : never]: T[K] };
```

And then combine them to get `ExtractProps`:

```
type ExtractProps<T, K extends keyof T, V = any> =
    PickByValue<Pick<T, K>, V>
```

Let's test it:

```
type Test1 = ExtractProps<Type, 'string' | 'number' | 'array'>;
/* type Test1 = {
    string: string;
    number: number;
    array: any[];
} */

type Test2 = ExtractProps<Type, 'string' | 'number' | 'array', Primitive>;
/* type Test2 = {
    string: string;
    number: number;
} */


type Test3 = ExtractProps<Type, 'string' | 'number', Primitive>;
/* type Test3 = {
    string: string;
    number: number;
} */
```

Looks good.

---

Note that you could also implement `ExtractProps` directly, by combining the functionality of `Pick` and `PickByValue` without using them:

```
type ExtractProps<T, K extends keyof T, V = any> =
    { [P in keyof T as T[P] extends V ? Extract<K, P> : never]: T[P] 
}
```

---

And finally, note that, as written in the question, your version of `ExtractProps` wants its second argument to be an *arraylike* type whose elements are keys.  You *could* do
that:

```
type ExtractPropsArray<T, KS extends Array<keyof T>, V = any> =
    PickByValue<Pick<T, KS[number]>, V>;
```

but the implementation does not care about the details of the array type other than the union of its element types.  It just throws away most of the information about `KS`.  I wouldn't recommend writing a type that demands information it doesn't actually need.  You can always unwrap the array before you use it, like `ExtractProps<T, KS[number], V>`, whereas inventing a useless array wrapper when you start with a keylike type is a bit silly, like `ExtractPropsArray<T, K[], V>` or `ExtractPropsArray<T, [K, K], V>`.  But that's ultimately more of an opinion than an authoritative source, so you should do it however you see fit.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACglgYwNYCEQDUCGAbArhAHgBUAaKdAPigF4AoKBqAbygG0BpKOAOyiQhAB7AGZQiUTAGcxHALpQIAD2ARuAE2nooAfiicAXFG4QAbhABOsw0TlQAvgG5atUJCgBRZecwJgMc4JgksRknEoq6tL8QqKk5DQS3CBUdIywiKgYOPgE8MghehRklM6u0J7A3r7+gZIAgubeIAXsAMoKyqoaUA1NBNEiYkXx1InJNPSMeZlYeITTLa2s3LgAtgBGFrLDlE60APQAVFBlHl4+fgFBLR0R3QOxxQmYSSmTDCysMFy8D2IS0hsMHk4S6mh0Z0qFwI7DIMCohmMZks1i+8lodigR0O+1K4GgRHxCSY7ygAHJJJUeABzMmGSnmGlONJklYbCx0oxrTbmZmMMnrQSCbAQF6cwXC0XcPkMMmYRqYECc3qKggvZIYlxE-xwVZwYBwMwJBk0qAAHy57PM5qgEpFLz2pyIEEpAEYEhUqpdasR8WQKVTuLSbazuRyQ-KmmSKE4jicic63cTSSag-TA9SZZaeYiw7zSZHFYZ1axZE5MTi8W5E8AAEwe87VK7BQmQf2p4MW0NWskRhVKuGMvUGswxg7HJ0uuvJtId9OMoNZtk57MWctQStVglTgDMDahTZ9rYg7Yzva7y45g91+sNEDHccnlL3oxJs4z86ZpMv5lzVvXOJAA)