# TypeScript function to get a key from object by its value

Tags: typescript

I want to write a TypeScript util helper called "KeyByValue" to get a key from object by its value. It is possible?

```
const keyStorage = {
  blue: 'car',
};

// so 

// type KeyByValue<val> = 
//                                           | value    | key
// I want a TypeScript helper --> KeyByValue<'car'> --> blue
```

Comment: Sounds like you want `KeysMatching` from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55153000/12299000).

Comment: Note that in the example code, the type of `keyStorage.blue` is `string` and not `"car"`.  So either you want `KeyByValue<string>` or you want `const keyStorage = {blue: "car"} as const`.  Either way it's kind of a too-minimal example since `keyof typeof keyStorage` is just `"blue"` no matter what.